# Как получить последние добавленные продукты (WooCommerce)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет!

Подскажите, как правильно составить запрос к WC/WP_Query на получение товаров-новинок?

Спасибо!

> UPD: есть мысль сравнивать $product->post_modified с настоящей датой и
>   если разница в датах не более 5 суток, то считать этот товар
>   'новинкой', но вот не знаю, на сколько это правильно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отсортировать по дате, задать количество:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'date_query'  => array(
        array(
            'after' => '5 days ago',
        ),
    ),
);

$r = new WP_Query( $query_args );
if ( $r->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $r->have_posts() ) {
        $r->the_post();
        // Вывод
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**UPDATE**

Добавлен запрос по дате `date_query`.

Comment: Сейчас добавлю про 5 суток

Comment: Добавил запрос по дате