# WP изменить запрос для вывода записей за последние 30 дней

Tags: php, wordpress, запрос, дата

Текущий запрос:

```
$popular_posts = get_posts("cat=-104&orderby=comment_count");
```

Надо вывести за последние 30 дней.
Что изменить в запросе?
Понимаю, что надо добавить `&` и можно через дату, например, за этот месяц вывести:
`$popular_posts = get_posts('cat=-104&orderby=comment_count&year=' . $year . '&monthnum=' . $month);`
предварительно обозначив:

```
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');
```

Но как поиграть со днями в запросе? Чтобы вывод был за последние 30 дней в get_posts. То есть, как в него передать через параметр `date_query`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771027/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-woocommerce

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить последние добавленные продукты (WooCommerce)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771027/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-woocommerce)

Comment: @KAGGDesign не увидел связи. Как в строку get_posts вывести резалт WP_Query ?  
По ТЗ я не могу переделать это в `have_posts()`

Comment: Не видите связи, потому что не читаете документацию: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts Функция get_posts() может принимать тот же массив параметров, что и Wp_Query(), и в конечном счёте, работает через Wp_Query. Добавьте в массив `date_query`

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну вот не доходит до меня логика WP... Подскажите, как добавить в `get_posts("cat=-104&orderby=comment_count");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код такой

```
$args = array(
    'category'   => - 104,
    'orderby'    => 'comment_count',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '30 days ago',
        ),
    ),
);

$popular_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно ещё вот так:

```
$args = array(
    'category'   => -104,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'comment_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days')) 
    )
); 
$posts = popular_posts ($args);
```